# How to get rid of "Authenticated with partial success" message when using two factor authentication

Tags: sshd, pam, two-factor-authentication

On my linux machine I am writing a PAM module for two factor authentication (https://github.com/kb100/signal-authenticator). It works on an opt in basis so if a user doesn't have a `.signal_authenticator` file the module just returns success. When sshing into the machine, it always tells me

```
Authenticated with partial success.
```

after the public key authentication succeeds. This is a nice intermediate message to see for those who have opted in to two-factor authentication, but for users who have not opted in it is confusing. They wonder why their authentication was only partially successful whereas in reality it was fully successful.

Is there some way to change this message or stop it from occurring?

Comment: what openssh version and distro? Can you provide whole log?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it is logged from openssh via logit. I was only able to disable via client side configuration LogLevel, configure it in .ssh/config like this:

```
Host *
    LogLevel ERROR
```

PS: There might be a mechanism to populate a default client side configuration on the server, I  did not find it yet. Please feel free to edit or let me know a short pointer.